# Image component cannot contain child even when child component position is absolute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a login form on Image. I did make the child position as `Absolute` but still, I am getting the following error:

> The **Image** component cannot contain children. If you want to render
>   content on to top of the image, consider using absolute positioning.

Below is my **Login.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Login extends Component<{}>{

  render (){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('../resources/images/background_image.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
            <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
            </View>
        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  loginContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
   bottom: 0,
   left: 0,
   right: 0
  },
});
```

Can somebody please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: could it be because of naming conventions? could you name your component to something other than Image? Maybe call you component ImgComp or something

Comment: as Html already has a tag called Image, it might be causing problems

Comment: The error is really clear: **cannot contain children**. This means you cannot put the `View` to be child of `Image`.

Comment: Just put the `View` tag below the `Image` tag. This means both `Image` and child `View` are children of top level `View`

Comment: @Khoa doesn't work I have tried it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ImageBackground component for this - just import it from 'react-native' as you would an image.

It takes children - so you would use it like this:

```
<ImageBackground source={ Img }>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Super useful but hard to find out about.

Answer (score 0):

as You brought official comment.

> The Image component cannot contain children. If you want to render
>   content on to top of the image, consider using absolute positioning.

Image can not contain children. (It was possible before, but not anymore)

The comment says 'using absolute positioning' does not mean you can contain children if you use absolute positioning.

It means you have to set another view's style as absolute and put it above your Image.

Comment: Tried making the top Level View as absolute but it still doesn't work

Comment: No, you should make 'child' View as absolute.

Comment: Although, like @dan674 answered, You can use ImageBackground, if you want to contain children inside Image.

Answer (score -1):

As the error suggests use `position: absolute` at the item that you want to position above the image.

My example is in HTML, but it should be similar.

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
  <figcaption>Img caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: As you can see in my code snipped, I want View (Login Container) above the image and it is markes as absolute

Comment: I think that the position absolute element should be the caption that is a sibling of the Image.

Comment: No, It doesnt have to be a caption